# Correct usage of strategy.order

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to use `strategy.order` for shorts in order to have 3 take profit levels (level 1 lowest TP and Level 3 highest TP) and execute when my stop loss is reached to exit the remaining position.

```
if (strategy.position_size >= 0 and high[1] < close)
    strategy.entry(id="EnterShort", long=false, qty = 1)
    shortHighEntery := close
    shortHighEnteryStoppLoss  :=high +1
else
    shortHighEntery := shortHighEntery[1]
    shortHighEnteryStoppLoss  :=shortHighEnteryStoppLoss[1]

exitShort = shortHighEntery *0.995 

stop_level = shortHighEnteryStoppLoss
take_level1 =  strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.0075)
take_level2 =  strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.015) 
take_level3 =  strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.045) 

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.order("Stop Loss Short", qty= 1, long=true, stop=stop_level, oca_name='Short', oca_type=strategy.oca.reduce)
    strategy.order("TP 1 Short", qty= 0.2, long=true, limit=take_level1, oca_name='Short', oca_type=strategy.oca.reduce)
    strategy.order("TP 2 Short", qty= 0.6, long=true, limit=take_level2, oca_name='Short', oca_type=strategy.oca.reduce)
    strategy.order("TP 3 Short", qty= 1, long=true, limit=take_level3, oca_name='Short', oca_type=strategy.oca.reduce)
```

It works at the begining, but unfortunately after a while it leads to a situation where my script *longs* which is never intended and then a mess starts. It seems like I don't understood the concept of either `oca_type=strategy.oca.reduce` or `long=yes`. But currently I have no clue on what I need to do.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you be more specific about what happens when 'a mess starts'? Do you get specific errors that you could add to your question?

Comment: first a short order is executed with 1 qty like intended. Than stop loss leads to closing the trade fine ending up in no position. After a while a while the script is going long instead switching between short and no position.

Comment: edited the inital code to make i more understandable the entery might not seem logical but its for demonstration purposes around myunderstanding issue with the strategy.order only. i dont get why its possible the code gos long. Because each executed stop loss or take profit should reduce the qty of the remaining TPs or stop loss ending up at 0 qty after the TP3 or if stop loss pops in before or between any TP. But its seems i am not seeing something here.